# OPE of two quasi-primaries involves only other quasi-primaries and their derivatives

Tags: resource-recommendations, conformal-field-theory

From Blumenhagen and Plauschinn *Introduction to Conformal Field Theory*, 2009:

> "The proof that the OPE of two quasi-primary fields involves indeed just other quasi-primary fields and their derivatives is non-trivial and will not be presented".

Does anybody know a good reference with a proof of this statement?

Comment: Any state in a quantum theory can be expanden into a complete basis of energy eigenstates. In a radially quantized CFT the hamiltonian is the dilation operator so the eigenstates are states of definite scaling dimension. Given the commutators of the conformal algebra one can increase the dimension by applying the momentum op. (derivatives). So it's not too strange that all eigenstates will be quasi-primaries and their descendants.